# How to (install and) use package in haskell

Tags: haskell, package

I'm trying to use [this xml package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml) in ghci.

What I already did in cmd:

> cabal install cabal-install
>
> cabal install xml-1.3.13.tar.gz

And the installation was succesful.
But how do I use this package inside my scripts and GHCi? I'm about to throw my pc out of the window atm...

Comment: What have you tried so far - e.g. with ghci? It should be in scope when you run `ghci` on its own, but if not `ghci -package xml` will definitely bring it in.

Comment: Thanks, I used 'ghci -package xml' in cmd and it worked. Do you maybe know how to use it in WinGHCi instead of cmd? Also, how can I use this in a '.hs' file? e.g.'import xml'

Comment: You don't import packages into Haskell modules, but modules that the package defines. Try e.g. `import Text.XML.Light` ...

Comment: As far as I can see it's still visible in winghci without any extra flags - does `:browse Text.XML.Light` produce anything? That works for me in ghci without any `-package` flags as well, though.

Comment: Before throwing the PC out of the Window, consider throwing Windows out of your PC. (SCNR)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To explicitly load the xml package in ghci, use:

```
ghci -package xml
```

A single *package* contains *modules*, which are the things you `import` from source code.

In this case we can see a list of them from the hackage page you linked to under the "Modules" heading. The highest-level module listed there is `Text.XML.Light` so I'd suggest starting from that:

```
import Text.XML.Light
```

and then look at the [documentation for that module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-1.3.13/docs/Text-XML-Light.html) to see what you can do with it.